# TrustZone monitor mode and IFAR, IFSR, DFAR, DFSR

Tags: arm, trustzone

The ARM [TrustZone monitor mode](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.prd29-genc-009492c/CACJBHJA.html) can trap aborts in monitor mode.  The monitor mode always executes in the secure world or context.  How can we know what address and reason caused a fault in the normal world when it traps to the monitor mode *instruction abort* and *data fault* vectors?

The [`IFSR`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0433b/CIHCEAAI.html), [`IFAR`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0433b/CIHBEDBC.html), [`DFSR`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0433b/CIHBEDBC.html) and [`DFAR`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0433b/CIHBEDBC.html) are banked *CP15* registers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is worth noting that only external aborts can be configured to be taken in monitor mode, so MMU access faults will not be trapped.

As for the main question: the state of all Secure/Non-secure banked registers *while in monitor mode* is controlled by the state of the cp15 Secure Configuration Register NS bit: when it is set, you access Non-secure versions, and when it is clear you access Secure versions.

The following is some inline `gcc` code which allows any *secure world* mode to inspect these `CP15` registers.

```
    #define MODE_MONITOR 0x16
    unsigned int mode;
    unsigned int world;
    unsigned int dfar;
    unsigned int dfsr;
    unsigned int ifar;
    unsigned int ifsr;

    asm (" mrs %0, cpsr\n"                 /* Save mode. */
         " mrc p15, 0, %1, c1, c1, 0\n"
         " orr  %1, %1, #1\n"              /* Set NS bit in SCR. */
         " cpsid aif, %6\n"                /* To monitor mode... */
         " mcr p15, 0, %1, c1, c1, 0\n"
         " mrc p15, 0, %2, c6, c0, 0\n"
         " mrc p15, 0, %3, c5, c0, 0\n"
         " mrc p15, 0, %4, c6, c0, 2\n"
         " mrc p15, 0, %5, c5, c0, 1\n"
         " bic  %1, %1, #1\n"              /* Clear NS bit in SCR. */
         " mcr  p15, 0, %1, c1, c1, 0\n"
         " isb\n"
         " msr cpsr, %0\n"
         : "=&r" (mode), "=&r" (world),
           "=r"(dfar), "=r"(dfsr),
           "=r"(ifar), "=r"(ifsr)
         : "I" (MODE_MONITOR));
    printf("DFAR: %.8x dfsr: %.8x IFAR: %.8x ifsr: %.8x\n",
           dfar, dfsr, ifar, ifsr);
```

Comment: It is very *weird*; are all banked `CP15` registers like this?  So when you are in monitor, the secure MMU state applies, but you can see the non-secure TTBR, etc if the *NS* bit is set?

Comment: Correct. Monitor mode is "special".

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on " So when you are in monitor, the secure MMU state applies, but you can see the non-secure TTBR, etc if the NS bit is set?"

Comment: @mSO: Monitor mode itself is _always_ Secure. So TLB entries allocated when executing in monitor mode, or any other Secure mode, are Secure (NSTID=0), regardless of state of NS bit.