# How to set carry flag on ARM to 0 or 1?

Tags: arm, carryflag

I couldn't find any tutorial on how to set the flags for the Carry on ARM to 1 or to 0. Can anybody help me out with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in [put ARM CPU in different modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295566/how-can-i-put-arm-processor-in-different-modes-using-c-program) and [linux's irqflags.h](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/irqflags.h), setting the mode, IRQ and carry flags can all be done in the same way.

Generally the macros is like,

```
.macro  set_cflag, temp_reg
mrs \temp_reg, cpsr
bic \temp_reg, \temp_reg, #(1<<29)
msr cpsr_f, \temp_reg 
.endm

.macro  clear_cflag, temp_reg
mrs \temp_reg, cpsr
orr \temp_reg, \temp_reg, #(1<<29)
msr cpsr_f, \temp_reg 
.endm
```

It is three steps,

1. Read the old value.
2. Update the flag in a working register.
3. Write the value back.

Some additional details are 'atomic' behaviour.  Ie, you might need to disable interrupts and memory faults, etc.  For some user code or a simple 'polling mode' bare metal, the above is fine.

If you really want to be 'efficient'; looking at your surrounding context and known registers you can execute some instruction that you **know** will set/clear the carry flag.  For instance, if R0 is '0' then `adds r0,r0,r0` will clear the carry flag.  An instruction like `eors R0,R0,R0` will not touch the carry bit.  It may depend on whether you also need to know about other NZV bits.  The notation 'cpsr_f' will only alter the NZCV bits.  You can use `msr cpsr_f, #NZCV_bits` if you want to set/clear all of these.  Ie, you don't care about the old value of all of them <sup>arch restrictions</sup> .  The other flags, like mode, IRQ, etc will remain untouched.

See also:

- [Heyrick on status register](https://www.heyrick.co.uk/armwiki/The_Status_register).
- [ARM Q bit](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0363g/Chdiajjd.html)