# Enter Hypervisor Mode on ARMv7 through Kernel Module

Tags: c, arm, virtualization, openwrt, hypervisor

I am working on a project where I have a router with ARMv7 processor (Cortex A15) and OpenWRT OS. I have a shell on the router and can load kernel modules with `insmod`.

My goal is to write a kernel module in C which changes the HVBAR register and then executes the hvc instruction to get the processor in the hyp mode.
This is a scientific project where I want to check if I can place my own hypervisor on a running system. But before I start to write my own hypervisor I want to check if and how I can bring the processor in the hyp mode.

According to this picture take from armv7-a manual B.9.3.4 the system must be in insecure mode, not in user mode and the SCR.HCE bit must be set to 1.

[image]

My question is how I can prepare the processor with a C kernel module and inline assembly and then execute the hvc instruction. I want to do this with a kernel module because then I start in PL1. This pseudocode describes what I want to achieve:

1. call smc     // to get in monitor mode
2. set SRC.HCE to 1 // to enable hvc instruction
3. set SRC.NS to 1 // to set the system to not secure
4. call hvc #0  // call the hvc instruction to produce a hypervisor exception

Comment: It is very unclear what you want to archive. Do you want to write your own hypervisor and run openwrt or you want to from openwrt enter the hypersivor mode. If the latter IMO is not possible and wrong.

Comment: I have updated my question. My goal is to call the hvc instruction from a C program/kernel module. But before I can do this I need to enable the hvc instruction in the system. My question is how a minimal C kernel module with inline assembly can look that first enables the hvc instruction and then executes it.

Comment: See: [tag:trust-zone].  When changing from secure to normal, 90+% of the CP15 registers aren't set.  Setting the CP15 registers is **NOT** a simple copy.  Some registers must be set in order/sequences that should be investigated on a case by case basis.  It is much better to have booted Linux from NORMAL mode in the first place.  See: [TZ monitor mode and IFAR, IFSR...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080918/trustzone-monitor-mode-and-ifar-ifsr-dfar-dfsr) for an inkling of your 'in-line' assembler. Contemplate changing linux-mm (MMU, caches, etc) under its feet.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to elevate privilege is to start off in the needed privilege mode already: You've a root shell. Is the boot chain verified? Could you replace bootloader or kernel, so your code naturally runs in PL2 (HYP) mode? If so, that's probably the easiest way to do it.

If you can't replace the relevant part of the boot chain, the details of writing the rootkit depend a lot on information about your system left out: In which mode is Linux started? Is KVM support enabled and active? Was PL2 initialized? Was it locked? Is there "secure" firmware you can exploit?

The objective is always the same: have `HVBAR` point at some code you can control and do a `hvc`. Depending on your environment, solutions may range from spraying as much RAM as possible with your code and hope (perhaps after some reboots) an uninitialized HVBAR would point at an instruction you control to inhibiting KVM from running and accessing the early hypervisor stub to install yourself instead.

Enumerating such exploits is a bit out of scope for a StackOverflow answer; this is rather dissertation material. Indeed, there's a doctoral thesis exactly on this topic:

[Strengthening system security on the ARMv7 processor architecture with hypervisor-based security mechanisms](https://depositonce.tu-berlin.de/handle/11303/6427)

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify HVBAR unless you are already in EL2 (Hyp) mode. You either need a trampoline service already setup for this or find some sort of exploit in an existing EL2/EL3 firmware service to run code with that privilege. Secure/Non-secure is a separate concept not directly related to the EL your code is running in.

If you look at the kernel code you will see the first thing the kernel does is check if the boot code started the kernel in EL2 at which point it installs the trampolines so it can get back to it. If the kernel is booted in EL1 it will never be able to re-enter Hyp mode.